# How to bring footer section beneath the body section: CSS Flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am having this hierarchy for the date picker. An input at the top, container at the bottom that opens up on input click, which has calendar panel and a footer. With the following I am getting the footer section to the next section instead of below. Can someone help?

Below pic shows expected output. Also padding is not getting applied to the borders of the calendar with calendar container should have the same width as the input field when opened

https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-rangepicker-6gmz85?file=/src/styles.scss:0-4380

```
.App{
  width: 350px; 
  height: 500px;
}
.custom-datepicker {
  .ant-picker-active-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}

.custom-datepicker-dropdown {
  .ant-picker-panel-container {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    .ant-picker-panels {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      .ant-picker-panel:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
      }
      :first-child {
        button.ant-picker-header-next-btn {
          visibility: visible !important;
        }
      }
    }
    .ant-picker-panel {
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      border: none;
      .ant-picker-date-panel {
        width: auto;
        .ant-picker-header{
          border-bottom: none;
        }
        .ant-picker-body {
          display: flex;
          place-content: center;
          padding: 10px 10px;
          .ant-picker-content {
            tr td:nth-child(7) {
              background-color: grey;
            }
            .ant-picker-cell {
              &.ant-picker-cell-in-view {
                &.ant-picker-cell-today {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    &::before {
                      border: green;
                      border-radius: 50%;
                    }
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-range-start {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    border-top-left-radius: 32px;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 32px;
                    background-color: green;
                  }
                  &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-start-single) {
                    &::before {
                      background-color: green;
                    }
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-range-end {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    border-top-right-radius: 32px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 32px;
                    background-color: green;
                  }
                  &:not(.ant-picker-cell-range-end-single) {
                    &::before {
                      background-color: green;
                    }
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-in-range {
                  &::before {
                    background-color: lightblue;
                  }
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                    color: blue;
                  }
                }
                &.ant-picker-cell-selected {
                  .ant-picker-cell-inner {
                       background-color: green;
                 }                
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .ant-picker-footer {
      border-top: none;
      flex: 1;
      display: flex;
      .ant-picker-footer-extra {
        .custom-dropdown-container {
          .custom-from-to-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            margin-top: 16px;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;   
            padding-bottom: 12px;         
            .custom-from-to-input-holder {
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              margin-bottom: 8px;
              .custom-range-text {
                margin-bottom: 8px;
                font-size: 11px;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-stretch: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                line-height: 16px;
                letter-spacing: 0.5px;                  }
              .custom-range-input {
                height: 30px;
                width: 90px;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
              }
            }
          }
          .custom-from-to-divider {
            width: 100%;
            height: 1px;
            margin: 0 16px;
            position: relative;
            top: 8px;
            background-color: black;
          }
          .custom-actions-holder {
            padding-top: 10px;
            .left-section {
               float: left;
            }
            .right-section {
              float: right;
              .today-button{
                margin-left:10px
              }
              .apply-button{
                margin-left:10px
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `.ant-picker-panel-container` class wraps two elements which is panel and footer. So, you need to add `flex-direction: column` property to `.ant-picker-panel-container` class which sets direction for them and will bring footer to the bottom, and allows padding around calendar to come into play as well.

Comment: The footer is getting attached to right most corner if I add that

Comment: Oops! I forgot to mention that you need to update styles for footer as well in order to make it look like one in the picture.
Just add `flex-direction: column` and `align-items: center` to `.ant-picker-footer` class and add width and padding to `.ant-picker-footer-extra` class, say `width: 252px` and `padding: 12px 0`.

Comment: On click of month or year from top, the style again moves to the top.